# Magento 2.3.2 > Some products images are broken and some are not loading correctly in frontend

Tags: magento2, product-images, catalog, magento2.3.2, media-images

I'm a new to magento and don't know much about magento, Recently I have installed a custom theme in magento2 and then some products images became broken and some are having images with `src=".../static/frontend/Mgs/claue/en_GB/MGS_Mpanel/images/blank.png"`
I know about `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` but my store have more than **31000** products images and this command will never complete,
what I have tried so far:

- Upgrade: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- Compile: `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- Deploy: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- Reindexing: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- Cache flush and clean using: `php bin/magento cache:flush` & `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- Flush Catalog Images Cache from Admin (backend)
- Changed permissions:

> ```
> find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
>
> find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
>
> chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
>
> chmod u+x bin/magento
> ```

Can you please help me with it? I have spent about one week by trying different solutions from stackexchange, stackoverflow and from other platforms but nothing work for me.
Please have a look at the frontend:

[image: Product with /blank.png]

[image: Product with Broken image]

Comment: try this command in project root dir(
sudo chmod -R 777 . )

Comment: @IZANOVA Thank you for your response, I have tried this solution but the problem is still there!

Comment: is images showing in product grid from admin side?

Comment: Yes, they are showing perfectly in Admin side

Comment: Changing rights to 777 is absolutely not recommended. The permission 777 means that any user on your operating system can modify, execute, and write to the files posing a significant security risk to your system. An unauthorized user could use this to modify files to compromise your system.

Comment: It looks like your theme (or an extension) is adding lazy-loading for images. You can see it in your screenshot in `img` element where `data-src` is set. Maybe there's a threshhold you have to scroll in order to trigger the lazy loading, but can't reach it because you are already at the bottom of the page. Or, the lazy loading is broken in general. Do you get any console errors? Maybe some other broken JS is blocking the scripts.

Comment: @Hoargarth Thank you for the information about permissions and the lazy loading, actually I got this error in the console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return regionHasElement('promotion') }"
Message: regionHasElement is not defined" and I have posted a question about it here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359548/magento2-3-2-uncaught-referenceerror-unable-to-process-binding-message-region

Comment: The most probably what's happening on your page is, the lazy loading is working for some images, then while not done yet that error happens which is stopping all further JS processing. I would concentrate on fixing that error first and see if the problem with images will be fixed with it

Comment: Thanks you for helping, I have tried to fix the error but got no luck, I'm new to magento and don't know what to do next with the error!