# Magento2.3.2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding, Message: regionHasElement is not defined

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, magento2.3.2, magento2minicart

I'm new to magento and don't know much about magento, Recently I have installed a custom theme in magento ver 2.3.2-p2 and the theme was working perfectly but then It start throwing the given error on home page:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if:
> function(){return regionHasElement('promotion') }"
> Message: regionHasElement is not defined

However, I have tested the home page and almost all the features are working perfectly but there is something wrong with the ***product listing*** that is the products images are shown initially and then it starts loading after 2 to 3 seconds. And I don't know if the given error caused this issue or not. Please I need your help for fixing the given error:

[image: regionHasElement is not defined]

What I have tried so far:

- Double-checking the custom theme-configuration from admin-backend
- Manually deleting `var/cache/*`, `generated/*` and `pub/static/*` and then running the commands given below

  - `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
  - `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
  - `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
  - `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
  - `php bin/magento cache:flush`
  - `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- Flush Catalog Images Cache from Admin (backend)
- Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache
- Double-checking the permissions for directories and files

Can you please help me in fixing the given error? I have spent much time by finding exact error and its solution in stackexchange, stackoverflow and from other platforms but nothing fix the error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure how you installed the theme, but it's either in `magento-root/app/design/frontend` or somewhere in `magento-root/vendor`folders. For the whole theme files, search for `regionHasElement `. It should be used in `.html` or `.phtml` files Javascript in an if / ifnot condition from knockout. From there you would have to debug from where the value is coming and why it is undefined. Maybe a setting is needed in admin backend, or it's a bug in the theme.

Comment: Magento itself is using a function in knockout called `regionHasElements`, note the additional `s` in it's name which is missing in your error message. So maybe it's just missing that s. See first comment to find the position and try to fix it. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` is needed after changing `.html` files

Comment: Thank you for helping and sure I am trying this fix.

Comment: @Hoargarth The file was located at `'app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html'` and I have renamed the `regionHasElement` to `regionHasElements` and deployed it then the same error is thrown: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return regionHasElements('promotion') }"
Message: regionHasElements is not defined"`

Comment: Do you know which version the theme has? Because in their changelog from `Version 2.1.7 – 27th Jun 2022` I can see a fix for minicart. Maybe you can try updating the theme in order to fix your problem

Comment: Oh it's my bad, I have installed v1.9.19. I was thinking that the error is thrown by some of my mistake but I was wrong and did not even look into the theme, I will update the theme. Thank you once again for your time and effort :)